# Get informed when Windows Scheduled tasks doesn't run

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

A have a few tasks created on "TaskScheduler", they run some code that informs me in case of failures, but I really needed some method to get informed if a task did not run, either because the machine was off or if whatever happened. I'm sure I'm not the first person with this problem, I'd guess there is some relatively native solution for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set up tasks to notify you on the event (from Event Viewer) of a **failed task**. But getting notified if the task didn't run when the PC was off would likely not be possible.

Comment: Since you cannot be informed if the machine is *off* (how could it send a message), you need the converse: Have the task inform you if it runs **successfully**, and take action when you **don't** get the expected success signal.